# How to create a new column containing two factor levels in the length of factor levels from another column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame called ldat_1. I want create a new column called `language` from the `Condition` column.
In the new `language` column, I need two factor levels called `english` and `malay`.

To create that `language` column, using the levels of `Condition` column, I want `"T2" "T3" "T4" "T5" "T6"` to become `english`, and `"TM2" "TM3" "TM4" "TM5" "TM6"` to become `malay`.

hear is my some code:

```
head(ldat_1)
  Subject Age Profi_CAT Domain Trial Condition word1      word2 word3    word4
1       1  22         1      2    15        T2 Some       birds   are   eagles
2       1  22         1      2    16        T3 Some  pineapples   are  flowers
3       1  22         1      2    17        T4   All     snakes   are reptiles
4       1  22         1      2    18        T5   All       fish   are   sharks
5       1  22         1      2    19        T6   All   lavender   are   fruits
6       1  22         1      2    21        T2 Some       birds   are     owls
  CorrectAnswer word4.CRESP word4.RESP word4.ACC word4.RT
1             c           c          c         1     1322
2             m           m          m         1     5736
3             c           c          c         1     1299
4             m           m          m         1     1388
5             m           m          m         1     1118
6             c           c          c         1     1170
> #check the condition column levels again
> levels(as.factor(ldat_1$Condition)) 
 [1] "T2"  "T3"  "T4"  "T5"  "T6"  "TM2" "TM3" "TM4" "TM5" "TM6"
```

hear is the dput of my data

```
dput(ldat_1)
structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Age = c(22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), Profi_CAT = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Domain = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Trial = c(15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 
66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 134L, 135L, 
136L, 137L, 138L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
87L, 88L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 115L, 
116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L), Condition = c("T2", 
"T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", 
"T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", 
"T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", 
"T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", 
"TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", 
"TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", 
"TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", 
"TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", 
"TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", 
"TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", 
"TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", 
"TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", 
"TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", 
"TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", "TM2", "TM3", "TM4", "TM5", "TM6", 
"T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", 
"T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", 
"T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", 
"T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", 
"T6"), word1 = c("Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", 
"Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", 
"All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", 
"All", "All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", 
"Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", 
"All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", 
"Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", 
"Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", 
"Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", 
"Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", 
"Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", 
"Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", 
"Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", 
"Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", 
"Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", 
"Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", 
"Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", 
"Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", 
"Semua", "Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", 
"Sesetengah", "Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Sesetengah", 
"Sesetengah", "Semua", "Semua", "Semua", "Some ", "Some ", "All", 
"All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", 
"Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", 
"All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", 
"All", "All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", 
"Some ", "All", "All", "All", "Some ", "Some ", "All", "All", 
"All"), word2 = c("birds", "pineapples", "snakes", "fish", "lavender", 
"birds", "strawberries", "dinosaurs", "fish", "lilies", "birds", 
"watermelons", "chameleons", "fish", "hibiscuses", "birds", "papayas", 
"tortoises", "fish", "roses", "birds", "grapes", "lizards", "fish", 
"orchids", "birds", "durians", "crocodiles", "fish", "jasmines", 
"birds", "coconuts", "iguanas", "fish", "tulips", "birds", "bananas", 
"frogs", "fish", "daisies", "birds", "mangos", "alligators", 
"fish", "rafflesias", "reptilia", "jerung", "lili", "serangga", 
"helang", "reptilia", "salmon", "mawar", "serangga", "penguin", 
"reptilia", "belut", "orkid", "serangga", "itik", "reptilia", 
"tuna", "melati", "serangga", "flamingo", "reptilia", "sardin", 
"tulip", "serangga", "merak", "reptilia", "keli", "daisi", "serangga", 
"itik", "reptilia", "patin", "rafflesia", "serangga", "angsa", 
"reptilia", "kerapu", "jejarum", "serangga", "merpati", "reptilia", 
"siakap", "teratai", "serangga", "kenari", "ikan", "lili", "nyamuk", 
"burung", "nanas", "ikan", "mawar", "cengkerik ", "burung", "tembikai", 
"ikan", "orkid", "belalang", "burung", "betik", "ikan", "melati", 
"semut", "burung", "anggur", "ikan", "tulip", "lebah", "burung", 
"durian", "ikan", "daisi", "pepatung", "burung", "kelapa", "ikan", 
"rafflesia", "lalat", "burung", "pisang", "ikan", "jejarum", 
"lipas", "burung", "mangga", "ikan", "teratai", "kumbang", "burung", 
"jambu", "fruits", "snakes", "sharks", "flowers", "butterflies", 
"fruits", "dinosaurs", "salmons", "flowers", "mosquitoes", "fruits", 
"chameleons", "anchovies", "flowers", "cockroaches", "fruits", 
"tortoises", "eels", "flowers", "grasshoppers", "fruits", "lizards", 
"guppies", "flowers", "ants", "fruits", "crocodiles", "piranha ", 
"flowers", "caterpillars", "fruits", "iguanas", "stingrays", 
"flowers", "ladybugs", "fruits", "frogs", "tuna", "flowers", 
"bees", "fruits", "alligators", "sardines", "flowers", "dragonflies"
), word3 = c("are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", "ialah", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", 
"are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are", "are"
), word4 = c("eagles", "flowers", "reptiles", "sharks", "fruits", 
"owls", "flowers", "reptiles", "salmons", "fruits", "penguins", 
"flowers", "reptiles", "anchovies", "fruits", "parrots", "flowers", 
"reptiles", "eels", "fruits", "sparrows", "flowers", "reptiles", 
"guppies", "fruits", "ostriches", "flowers", "reptiles", "piranha ", 
"fruits", "ducks", "flowers", "reptiles", "stingrays", "fruits", 
"flamingoes", "flowers", "reptiles", "tuna", "fruits", "peacocks", 
"flowers", "reptiles", "sardines", "fruits", "ular", "burung", 
"bunga", "nyamuk", "ikan", "sesumpah", "burung", "bunga", "cengkerik", 
"ikan", "cicak", "burung", "bunga", "belalang", "ikan", "buaya", 
"burung", "bunga", "semut", "ikan", "katak", "burung", "bunga", 
"lebah", "ikan", "penyu", "burung", "bunga", "pepatung", "ikan", 
"komodo", "burung", "bunga", "lalat", "ikan", "iguana", "burung", 
"bunga", "lipas", "ikan", "dinasour", "burung", "bunga", "kumbang", 
"ikan", "jerung", "buah", "serangga ", "helang", "bunga", "salmon", 
"buah", "serangga ", "penguin", "bunga", "belut", "buah", "serangga ", 
"itik", "bunga", "tuna", "buah", "serangga ", "flamingo", "bunga", 
"sardin", "buah", "serangga ", "merak", "bunga", "keli", "buah", 
"serangga ", "gagak", "bunga", "patin", "buah", "serangga ", 
"angsa", "bunga", "kerapu", "buah", "serangga ", "merpati", "bunga", 
"siakap", "buah", "serangga ", "kenari", "bunga", "pineapples", 
"insects", "fish", "lavender", "reptiles", "strawberries", "insects ", 
"fish", "lilies", "reptiles", "watermelons", "insects", "fish", 
"hibiscuses", "reptiles", "papayas", "insects", "fish", "roses", 
"reptiles", "grapes", "insects", "fish", "orchids", "reptiles", 
"durians", "insects", "fish", "jasmines", "reptiles", "coconuts", 
"insects", "fish", "tulips", "reptiles", "bananas", "insects", 
"fish", "daisies", "reptiles", "mangos", "insects", "fish", "rafflesias", 
"reptiles"), CorrectAnswer = c("c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", 
"m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", 
"m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", 
"c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", 
"c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", 
"m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", 
"m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", 
"c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", 
"c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", 
"m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", 
"m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", 
"c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", 
"c", "m", "c", "m", "m"), word4.CRESP = c("c", "m", "c", "m", 
"m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", 
"c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", 
"c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", 
"m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", 
"m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", 
"c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", 
"c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", 
"m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", 
"m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", 
"c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", 
"c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m"), word4.RESP = c("c", "m", 
"c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"c", "m", "m", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "c", "c", 
"m", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", 
"c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", 
"c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "m", "m", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", 
"m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", 
"m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", 
"c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", 
"c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", 
"m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", 
"m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m"), word4.ACC = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), word4.RT = c(1322L, 5736L, 1299L, 1388L, 1118L, 
1170L, 2502L, 5120L, 1826L, 3108L, 1824L, 3470L, 1230L, 1921L, 
2428L, 1654L, 2500L, 1697L, 5111L, 1485L, 1349L, 3644L, 1237L, 
4461L, 1001L, 3147L, 1414L, 3246L, 1974L, 2243L, 2840L, 1082L, 
1912L, 6255L, 1209L, 3435L, 1051L, 5340L, 7722L, 1359L, 1107L, 
937L, 772L, 4442L, 816L, 1462L, 2982L, 984L, 2967L, 3334L, 1769L, 
615L, 1011L, 557L, 919L, 885L, 847L, 998L, 628L, 761L, 808L, 
696L, 1841L, 739L, 554L, 1892L, 576L, 475L, 1427L, 803L, 1994L, 
533L, 482L, 919L, 1411L, 580L, 593L, 410L, 1747L, 946L, 788L, 
568L, 617L, 974L, 634L, 4413L, 1541L, 519L, 2237L, 3064L, 7088L, 
1622L, 2528L, 1316L, 2367L, 1259L, 1012L, 824L, 1043L, 1041L, 
1823L, 768L, 949L, 2373L, 762L, 1680L, 773L, 881L, 1314L, 1405L, 
1427L, 763L, 762L, 1396L, 684L, 1763L, 3450L, 424L, 1726L, 765L, 
1824L, 833L, 528L, 2458L, 678L, 2119L, 668L, 972L, 1110L, 1792L, 
1239L, 573L, 550L, 1261L, 1032L, 1777L, 1407L, 1043L, 2756L, 
3434L, 1399L, 854L, 799L, 1762L, 1537L, 1422L, 1474L, 1062L, 
1896L, 4744L, 1969L, 803L, 966L, 1134L, 4563L, 2428L, 1253L, 
799L, 4083L, 3576L, 1704L, 1040L, 863L, 1329L, 4868L, 1323L, 
1451L, 1192L, 2678L, 5632L, 1760L, 796L, 1730L, 1777L, 1220L, 
1134L, 721L, 1076L, 1886L, 2329L)), row.names = c(NA, -180L), class = "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, use `grepl` to detect if `Condition` contains `"TM"`, if so, assign `"malay"`, otherwise assign `"english"`. This works fine since you have only two possibilities.

```r
dat$language <- ifelse(grepl("TM", dat$Condition), "malay", "english")
```

Answer (score 0):

a more general solution:

```
## build a named lookup vector:
language_lookup <- structure(
    c(rep('english',5),
      rep('malay',5)
      ), 
    names = c(paste0('T', 2:6),
              paste0('TM',2:6)
              )
)

## lookup the vector value (language) by vector name (condition)
df$language <- language_lookup[df$Condition]
```